send email using multiple domain emails using main domain postfix smtp server
I have a domain with postfix for SMTP server, eg EM-NAME.DOMAINNAME.COM
We are sending emails in bulk from domain email no-reply@EM-NAME.DOMAINNAME.COM
I am trying to send emails on behalf of my client email address, eg no-reply@CLIENT.CLIENTDOMAIN.COM
We are currently running into an issue with sending on behalf of some of our clients as the DMARC is failing - due to a mismatch in the header.
DKIM and SPF are both passing.
We have access to the sub domains we are just wondering if we are missing any DNS records that are necessary for us to fully authenticate these emails, so they are DMARC compliant.
We have set up an spf, dkim and dmarc record on the sub domain.
Any help in this scenario?
Thanks

For DMARC, the SPF or DKIM authenticated hostname has to be aligned with the domain/hostname used in the  From header. That is explained on every DMARC tutorial ever written, so I'm afraid there's no use of explaining it again here.
